# Unable to configure Spring Mobile Spring 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-mobile

I have a Spring Boot application where I want (for a start) to detect whether my device is mobile or browser. Therefor I thought Spring mobile is a good idea. The problem is that I can't get it going.

**CODE:**
Based on the official docs [here](https://projects.spring.io/spring-mobile/) I implemented the following:

```
public class DeviceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

@Bean
public DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor 
        deviceResolverHandlerInterceptor() {
    return new DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor();
}

@Bean
public DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver 
        deviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
    return new DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(deviceResolverHandlerInterceptor());
}

@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(deviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
}


}
```

and in my Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/user/mobile")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and hasRole('ROLE_MOBILE')")
public ModelAndView routeToUserInterfaceServiceMobile(final RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs,Device device) {
    System.out.println(device.isMobile());
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("session_userId", userAuthRepository.findByUsername(auth.getName()).getId());
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+MyConstants.PATH_USER_MOBILE_SERVICE);

    }
```

and the pom.xml additions:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Problem:**
I can run the application but when I call this endpoint I get the following error:

> No primary or default constructor found for interface
>   org.springframework.mobile.device.Device
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor
>   found for interface org.springframework.mobile.device.Device at
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:219)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:139)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:165)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>   at

Is there something else to add? Or is there something to add to spring properties?

Comment: Add `@Configuration` to your `DeviceConfig` class. Currently it is being unused.

Comment: Yeah just a second ago when i explained the problem to my collegue I got I too :D Thank you for your answer, that solved the problem.